# What is happening behind the scenes when calling object.method() and Class.method(object)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I am pretty new to Python and am tackling OOP. I am a bit confused as to when to use calls to methods and classes. The sample code below outputs the average, however I am curious as to when you would use calling from the Class vs methods from a real-world perspective. I'm pretty sure this is just something that I may have yet to tackle, but it's just been a bit of a confusion as to when I would use one over the other.

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, new_name, new_grades):
        self.name = new_name
        self.grades = new_grades

    def average(self):
        return sum(self.grades) / len(self.grades)

student_one = Student('Test User', [70, 88, 90, 99])

# object.method()
print(student_one.average())

# Class.method(object)
print(Student.average(student_one))
```

Comment: They are functionally equivalent. Strictly speaking `object.method()` is calling a bound method in `object`. The `class` call is using an unbound method but explicitly passing in the object. If you are manipulating instance state always use, `object.method()`... reserve `class.method()` for [`@classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=classmethod#classmethod) or [`@staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=staticmethod#staticmethod) functions.

Comment: You would always use `student_one.average()`

Answer (score 4):

In your example, there is no difference. **Use the first way.** The second way makes it appear as though you need to use "the back door" for some reason, for example if `student_one` was not actually a `Student` instance but you wanted to specifically call the `average` method of the `Student` class.

If an experienced Python developer were to read your code, seeing `Student.average(student_one)` may make them pause for a moment and wonder why the author wants to use the unbound `average` here. It would be an unusual style, and perhaps could imply that there may be something more subtle happening than there really was - a stumbling block.

For what's going on behind the scenes, the first way uses a [*bound method*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-method) and the second way just uses a normal [function](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-function).

```
>>> Student.average
<function __main__.Student.average(self)>
>>> student_one.average 
<bound method Student.average of <__main__.Student object at 0xcafef00d>>
```

A bound method is just a function which is bound to an instance, via [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors)*, and the instance ("self") is passed as the first positional argument implicitly:

```
>>> student_one.average.__self__ is student_one 
True
>>> student_one.average.__func__ is Student.average 
True
```

By using the function on the class and passing in the instance explicitly, you essentially do the same thing as an invocation of the descriptor does automatically.

For a deeper understanding of what a method is, there's detailed documentation of this binding process in the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html).

* <sub>Just a fancy way of saying via the "." i.e. the dotted attribute access</sub>

Comment: The "back door" explanation is very helpful. So it seems like I would only want to call from the class if there are any instances that would require me to access the average method (perhaps to do a similar calculation for those that are not a student). object.method() it is!

Comment: @AntonioSaqueton Yes, you got it.